# How can I build an html table from a List<dynamic> with col headers that you don't know until runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i run the following method and create an html table in the partial view, complete with column headers from "list".  The part that I cannot figure out is how can i create col headers for the "cols" i get from:

```
 foreach (var stepItem in ChainSteps)
            {
                var x = pttDB.Directs_Details.Where(o => o.activity_detail_id == lineItem.id && o.chain_detail_id == stepItem.Chain_Detail_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                dynamicModel.Add(stepItem.Step, x.percentage);
            }
```

list is of type `List<dynamic>`

```
public ActionResult chainList(string chainCode, List<Activity_Details> oList)
    {

            var filterDirects = oList.Where(c => c.chainid == chainCode).ToList();
            var ChainSteps = eeDB.Chains_Detail.Where(c => c.chainID == chainCode).OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
            var list = new List<dynamic>();
            //Loop the line item
            foreach (var lineItem in filterDirects)
            {

                dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
                var dynamicModel = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
                var wbs = from w in eeDB.WBS_Structure
                          where w.id == lineItem.wbs_id
                          select new { wbsTask = w.Task_Subtask_Combine }.ToString();
                var activityCode = from w in eeDB.Activity_Basis
                                   where w.id == lineItem.activity_code_id
                                   select new { activityCode = w.Activity_Code }.ToString();
                var activityName = from w in eeDB.Activity_Basis
                                   where w.id == lineItem.activity_code_id
                                   select new { activityName = w.Description }.ToString();
                dynamicModel.Add("WBS", wbs);
                dynamicModel.Add("Activity Code", activityCode);
                dynamicModel.Add("Activity Name", activityName);
                dynamicModel.Add("PTT Descriptionn", lineItem.Description);
                dynamicModel.Add("Original Budget", lineItem.Qty * lineItem.Unit_Rate);
                foreach (var stepItem in ChainSteps)
                {
                    var x = pttDB.Directs_Details.Where(o => o.activity_detail_id == lineItem.id && o.chain_detail_id == stepItem.Chain_Detail_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                    dynamicModel.Add(stepItem.Step, x.percentage);
                }
                list.Add(dynamicModel);
            }
            return PartialView("_chainList", list);

    }
```

Comment: so, all you want to know is how to render a < table > with the property names of your `dynamic` as column headers?

Comment: yes.  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least for ExpandoObject...

_chainlist.cshtml:

```
@model IDictionary<string,object>

<h1>A dynamic table...</h1>
<table>
<tr>
@foreach(var kvp in Model)
{
@:<th>@kvp.Key</th>
}
</tr>
<tr>
@foreach(var kvp in Model)
{
@:<td>@kvp.Value.ToString()</td>
}
</tr>
</table>
```